# Javascript input id value to url

Tags: javascript, url, input, linked-list, iteration

I would appreciate any help to build a basic javascript that would extract the forum input name value and create a new URL from the value that is extracted, and repeat with the new URL until the value that extracted is -1. That would be the final URL. Once found the final url will be opened.

For example if the source code states that

```
<input name="nextPage" ... value="10908071">
```

The script would extract the `nextPage` value which is `10908071` and input it into the url thus forwarding to `www.url.com/xyz?page=10908071`

When the next url is identified the script will loop and extract the nextPage value once again until the value is -1.

Once the value is -1 the final web url will be found and preferably opened.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

p.s. this is my first post, I would always find my answer here without the need to post but this seems a bit more complicated.

Comment: How will it loop?

Comment: Where’s the code you need help with?

Comment: It would loop by loading the next page via the value, open it and extract the next value again untill the value is -1, then there is no next page.

Comment: Did you try writing any code? Did you try googling for `find input by name in javascript`, `get input value in javascript` ? The rest of the code is `if(value == -1)`, so I suggest giving it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a loop and make network requests until you get to the desired value:

```
async function findURL() {
  let value;
  const baseURL = window.location.href; // I assume this is eg 'www.url.com/xyz'
  let pageURL = baseURL;
  while (value !== '-1') {
    const response = await fetch(pageURL);
    const responseText = await response.text();
    const responseDocument = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(responseText, 'text/html');
    value = responseDocument.querySelector('input[name="nextPage"]').value;
    if (value !== '-1') pageURL = baseURL + '?page=' + value;
  }
  // final URL found, redirect to its page:
  window.location.href = pageURL;
}
```

But you'll have to be *pretty certain* that the value eventually ends up being `-1`.

Comment: This is very useful, I have not coded is ages and this made me realize what I lack. Would i be able to create this into a userscript?

Comment: Sure, it's valid Javascript, so you can use it in a userscript.

Comment: You are a great help! I have tried to copy paste into tampermonkey and got errors off async. Got the errors to go away by wrapping with /* jshint ignore:start */ /* jshint ignore:end */ when on the site the script does nothing. Sorry for the desperation of help from a script kiddy.

Comment: ESLint is quite superior to JSHint, I'd turn off JSHint if I were you. What do you mean, "does nothing", what's the error?

Comment: That's not a Tampermonkey error, that's an (obsolete) linter warning - the code is still valid, and can be used in Tampermonkey much, much more easily than via console.

Comment: Just paste it in and run the function..?

Comment: Again, that's not an error, that's your obsolete linter (which doesn't understand modern Javascript syntax) being stupid. Disable your linter and look for *errors* rather than *linter warnings*. I'm assuming you're on a relatively modern browser, right?

Comment: This is pretty off-topic, just google it or look through the options, it's pretty obvious

Comment: Thank you for your help I will move this to a new topic. Youre the first to help me directly on this website.